# Mac: Excel VBA - Do HTTP request to website with XPath and get value

Tags: excel, vba, macos, xpath, terminal

I would like to get the value of a specified XPath of a website in Excel. However, I always get 0 returned in my spreadsheet...

This is my code so far:

```
Function HTTPGet2() As String

    HTTPGet2 = MacScript("do shell script ""xmllint --html -xpath 'string(//*[@id=""AssetAllocationLongShortTable1""]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1])' http://tools.morningstar.de/de/xray/default.aspx\?LanguageId\=de-DE\&PortfolioType\=2\&SecurityTokenList\=F000000EM3\]2\]0\]ETEXG$XETR\|F00000J8T2\]2\]0\]FODEU$$ALL\&values\=50.00\|50.00\&CurrencyId\=EUR\&from\=editholding""")

End Function
```

If I execute this function in the terminal everything works fine!
But in the excel I get returned only a `#VALUE!` in the selected cell..

Could you guys may help me and explain whats wrong and help me out?
Don't forget, I am using a Mac!

Kind regards and Thank You!

Comment: your function is inconsistent. It is named HTTPGet2  but attempts to return HTTPGet

Comment: Still no change.. I fixed it, now I get displayer #Value!

Comment: Is it possible that the default shell Excel is launching doesn't have `xmllint` on the path?  Can you try it with a simpler URL/xpath?

Comment: Test your function by calling it from a Sub instead of a worksheet cell.

Comment: @TimWilliams how do I do that?

Comment: `Sub Tester(): Debug.Print HTTPGet2(): End Sub`